# Search engines are gone from firefox

Tags: firefox, search

Suddenly after installing and uninstalling some toolbars, search engines are gone from firefox.

If I go to manage search engines I see nothing.

If I click Get more search engines I got nothing.

The search bar doesn't work. I can type google.com, etc. and it does nothing.

Some says I got to remove search.json from my firefox profile

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/990365

It doesn't work. It isn't created.

Reinstalling firefox doesn't help.

Only happen in one user in my computer.

Comment: Delete the user's firefox profile manually and see if the problem still exists.

Comment: How many toolbars? Like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/khmAf.jpg) many?

Answer (score 0):

Open Firefox while keeping the shift key pressed. You will be shown a dialog box that asks if you want to start Firefox in "Safe Mode" or "Reset Firefox" (or something similar in older Firefox versions).

Try to start Firefox in "Safe Mode" to see if this is an extension problem. If it doesn't work try to reset Firefox. As last resource delete your profile directory and start a new profile.